# Probability that a random jump decreases a distance to a previously specified point

Tags: probability, random-walk

I am thinking about the following problem that probably is already solved somewhere. Perhaps you have an idea.. Lets assume that a particle jumps constantly in a random direction (isotropic) but with a constant jump length. The question is, as the title already says, what is the probability that a jump takes the particle closer to a specific point. This should depend of course on the distance to the point and the jump length. I would like to have a solution for 2 dimensions. Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a drawing of the point and the particle, then added a black circle centered at the point with radius equal to the distance (say $d$), and a green circle centered at the particle, with radius equal to the jump length (say $r$).

[image]

You want the length of the arc between the two green lines, as a proportion of $2\pi r$. Alternatively, the angle $\angle BAC$ as a proportion of $360^\circ$.

We have
$$
\angle BAC = 180^\circ - \frac12\angle BPC = 180^\circ - \angle APC
$$
Now note that $\triangle APC$ is an isosceles triangle with sides $d, d, r$. Thus we can use trigonometry to find the angle at $P$. The law of cosines yields
$$
r^2 = d^2 + d^2 - 2d^2\cos\angle APC\\
\cos\angle APC = \frac{2d^2 - r^2}{2d^2} =1- \frac{r^2}{2d^2}\\
\angle APC = \arccos\left(\frac{2d^2 - r^2}{2d^2} =1- \frac{r^2}{2d^2}\right)
$$
Thus the probability of the particle getting closer after a jump is
$$
\frac{\angle BAC}{360^\circ} = \frac{180^\circ - \arccos\left(1-\frac{r^2}{2d^2}\right)}{360^\circ}
$$
(If you do this on a calculator, make sure to either convert this answer to radians, or set the calculator to degrees.)

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks for you ansatz. I am just a bit confused. First because if I plot the solution [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(pi-cos%5E-1(1-1%5E2%2Fx%5E2+))%2F(2+pi)++from+0+to+2) the probability is going to zero at a distance which doesn't make sense. Second I think the first equation is wrong. Shouldn't it be BAC=360-BPC? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the probability should go to zero for 0.5*r=d

Comment: @HighwayJohn For the second question, if we let $D$ be a point on the left half of the black circle, then $\angle BAC + \angle BDC = 180^\circ$. We also have $\angle BPC = 2\angle BDC$. Put those together, and you get what I have.

Comment: @HighwayJohn A $2$ had disappeared from $2d^2$ in the denominator.

Comment: Ah perfect, I got it and now its correct :) Huge thanks!